# phonegap facebook plugin share pictures directly

Tags: cordova

I'm using Phonegap Facebook Plugin. It works fine.
I'm trying to share a pictures from my phonegap app to facebook. It works.

But i would like to know if there is a way to publish directly on my facebook, skipping the dialog window [image]

Comment: You can public directly via opengraph if the user has authorized your application. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: Have you got some example? May i use open graph with Phonegap Facebook Plugin?